# Why do my section titles appear at the side of the UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

As attached in the picture.

I'm using a SearchDisplayController as well to facilitate searching.

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100809-c1fqumami2gtg1ytrjikmbcrpf.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100809-c1fqumami2gtg1ytrjikmbcrpf.jpg)

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if(searching)
        return nil;
    else
        return keys;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you implemented the method - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
you will return a NSArray with titles for the Indexes - as you do actually.
If you don't want to make em appear at any time, just delete this method.

If you want to make it appear:
Do the keys also appear if you clicked into the UISearchBar?
Since you always return the keys if someone is not using looking for something.

And of course, don't forget to use

```
searching = true;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

In the search-method.